# What is a Brutal Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Brutal Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Brutal Words™ | Not Brutal Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TIGER | LION |
| MILLS | FACTORIES |
| JOLLY | HAPPY |
| PECAN | CASHEW |
| INGOT | MOLD |
| CHEER | DELIGHT |
| CHAIN | STRING |
| SORRY | APOLOGIES |

CSV Version:

```
Brutal Words™,Not Brutal Words™
TIGER,LION
MILLS,FACTORIES
JOLLY,HAPPY
PECAN,CASHEW
INGOT,MOLD
CHEER,DELIGHT
CHAIN,STRING
SORRY,APOLOGIES
```

These are not the only examples of Brutal Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Brutal Words are

> words that yield other words under a ROT cipher (also known as a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)).

For example,

> TIGER is PECAN (ROT22)
>  MILLS is SORRY (ROT6)
>  JOLLY is CHEER (ROT19)
>  PECAN is TIGER (ROT4)
>  INGOT is CHAIN (ROT20)
>  CHEER is JOLLY (ROT7)
>  CHAIN is INGOT (ROT6)
>  SORRY is MILLS (ROT20)

This puzzle was obvious to me because

> I used the TIGER/PECAN transformation in one of my own [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/cryptic-chain-1).

The name comes from the fact that

> Julius Caesar was brutal.

I wonder what the longest Brutal Word is?

Comment: You are correct! By the way, the Brutal Words I mentioned are all tied for the longest Brutal Word :)

Comment: Oh, I remember Caesar's tiger. The longest Brutal Words I could find are, NOWHERE / ABJURER and [PURPURA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purpura) / [CHECHEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chechnya). They can all be found in the online OED.

Comment: Oh, I didn't find the nowhere/abjurer one. Nice!

Comment: ONE and BAR are the shortest Brutal words, I believe.

Comment: I'd think I and A are the shortest.